# What does `JIT is disabled` mean in Apple's JavaScriptCore (JSC) documentation

Tags: javascriptcore

I'm reading this documentation on NativeScript and it states the following about Apple's JavaScriptCore (JSC) Virtual Machine:

> It is responsible for the JavaScript code processing. A good analogy
>   may be made with the way Node.js processes JavaScript and translates
>   it to the underlying system APIs. We are handling each getter/setter
>   on JavaScript objects and dynamically call iOS APIs when needed. The
>   virtual machine is loaded in the application's process and operates on
>   the main UI thread. **Apple does not allow JIT in AppStore Apps so the
>   JIT is disabled in our build**.

I'm curios about the bolded sentence. What does it mean? If `VM` is disabled, how is JavaScript interpreted?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what disabled is the `JIT`, not the whole `VM`, the `VM` could only execute js code in slower interpret mode, because ios will kill any 3rd process who dares to run dynamic generated code--which is the core of JIT.